# sql server - Counting and then summing the same column by view method

Tags: sql-server

I'd like to write functionality to count and then sum the same column. In the below example: `e.id`  in the column `qtde empregados`. I'd like to get the total times that `e.id` is repeated.

```
create view v8 as
select e.nome 'empregado' , count(e.id) 'qtde empregados' from empregado e
where e.id_sup != 0
group by e.nome

select * from v8
```

Below is my result:

[image: Result]

Comment: don't use screenshot for your code. instead type the code in your question. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: please post your desired result

Comment: I've tried to do it , but I can't even post cause idk why it has appeared red highlight text

Comment: Please post the result that you want to get

Comment: in column "qtde empregados" I wanna show the total sum , therefore I just  see value 1

Comment: Look, we can't really understand your issue. If you post some sample data, show the result of your current query and then post the result that you would want to get, it would be a much better question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sum of the count of a field grouped by something, is really just the total count.

If I understand correctly you want:

```
SELECT SUM([Q].[qtde empregados]) AS [qtde empregados]
FROM (
    select e.nome 'empregado' , count(e.id) 'qtde empregados' from empregado e
    where e.id_sup != 0
    group by e.nome
) AS [Q]
```

But that is mathematically equivalent to the much simpler:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM empregado e
WHERE e.id_sup != 0
```

both will return 15

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why you'd want it but

```
select e.nome 'empregado' 
     , count(e.id) 'qtde empregados'
     , sum(e.id) 'whatever'
 from empregado e
where e.id_sup != 0
group by e.nome
```

Comment: I did it , but I'd like the result of column "qtde empregados" as sum, anyway  as I have my recordset is 15 my sum would equal 15 too only I wanna do. However Idk how to do it . where you see 1  I wanna sum. eg; 1+1+1+1+1... = 15 , can u understand me now ?

Comment: @AriölV alright, this will be the last time I post this comment, but **please just post the result that you want to get**

Comment: are you trying to get a total at the bottom ?

as in 

select * from v8
union select null,count(*) from v8